# py.test trying to import wrong module on Travis but not locally

Tags: travis-ci, pytest

I have [a Travis CI build that is failing](https://travis-ci.org/w3c/wpt-tools/jobs/148078878); `py.test` seems to be trying to import the wrong module, though I cannot reproduce this locally. I expect it to import `tools.lint.tests.test_lint`, not `lint.tests.test_lint`, as you can see in the traceback, given that build has `--full-trace`! This leads to the error beneath it when it tries to do a relative import from the tools package.

The short trackback is:

```
___________________ ERROR collecting lint/tests/test_lint.py ___________________
.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
lint/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from . import lint
lint/lint.py:15: in <module>
    from .. import localpaths
E   ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Given the name of the top level package is just the directory that the repo is in, I wouldn't be surprised to see that differ—but I'd still expect to see it there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the path Travis has that file at: `/home/travis/build/w3c/wpt-tools/lint/tests/test_lint.py`. The directory called `tools` on your computer is called `wpt-tools` on Travis, following the name of the repo on GitHub.

Vitally, `wpt-tools` isn't a valid Python package name, as Python packages cannot contain hyphens in the name. (They have to be an [identifier](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier)). This leads `py.test` to conclude it isn't a package, despite the `__init__.py` contained within, and hence it doesn't include it in the import path, leading to the error when code tries a relative import from what is meant to be the top-level package.

There's a couple of solutions here:

- The possibly simple one is renaming the repository so that it doesn't contain any hyphens, though obviously if you're an established repository this is likely undesirable.
- Get Travis CI to run the code from some directory, by copying/moving the repository to a directory whose name doesn't contain a hyphen, at the start of `before_install`, using something like:

  ```
  before_install:
    - mv `pwd` /tmp/tools
    - cd /tmp/tools
  ```

  This will then run all the install and later steps from `/tmp/tools`, which will allow everything to run as expected.

  (Note you cannot use a symbolic link here as `os.getcwd()` in Python will eliminate the link from the path, returning the real path, leading that seeming workaround not to work at all.)